# VBA for Word script to auto set "keep with next"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a multi-level list linked to the following styles:

```
List Number 
List Number 1 
List Number 2 
...
```

I want to write a VBA script that sets every paragraph with any of these styles to "keep with next"
only when the next paragraph is a deeper level.

I have the following code, but it doesn't appear to make any changes:

```
Sub SetKeepWithNext()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim style As style
    Dim nextPara As Paragraph
    Dim nextStyle As style
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Iterate through all paragraphs in the document
    For i = 1 To doc.Paragraphs.Count - 1
        Set para = doc.Paragraphs(i)
        
        ' Check if the paragraph has a style and it starts with "List Number"
        If para.style <> "" And Left(para.style, 11) = "List Number" Then
            Set style = para.style
            
            ' Check if the next paragraph has a style
            If i + 1 <= doc.Paragraphs.Count Then
                Set nextPara = doc.Paragraphs(i + 1)
                If nextPara.style <> "" Then
                    Set nextStyle = nextPara.style
                    
                    ' Compare the outline level of the paragraphs
                    If nextPara.OutlineLevel > para.OutlineLevel Then
                        style.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True ' never executed
                    Else
                        style.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I would also like to set "keep with next" for any paragraph (style ignored) that ends with a colon.

Comment: What community guideline does this allegedly violate?

Comment: I suppose the downvote results from [It doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). I would config the styles to have "KeepWithNext" - and then your VBA checks for the condition and applies "KeepWithNext" = false to the **paragraph** - but not to the style

Comment: It is impossible for any paragraph in a Word document to not have a style so `para.style <> ""`  is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code - I am assuming that all List Number-styles have set "keep with next" to true.

```vb
Public Sub checkKeepWithNext()
Dim p As Paragraph
For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    p.Range.Select
    If p.Style Like "List Number*" Then
        If p.Next.OutlineLevel > p.OutlineLevel Then
            p.keepWithNext = False
        End If
    ElseIf getLastCharacterOfParagraph(p) = ":" Then
        p.keepWithNext = True
    End If
Next
End Sub

Public Function getLastCharacterOfParagraph(p As Paragraph) As String

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = p.Range
rg.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
getLastCharacterOfParagraph = rg.Characters.Last

End Function
```

If Styles are not set to "keepWithNext" then use this check:

```
    If p.Style Like "List Number*" Then
        If p.Next.OutlineLevel <= p.OutlineLevel Then
            p.keepWithNext = true
        End If
```

Comment: I don't have these styles set to "keep with next. The colon set works, but the numbering doesn't.

Comment: see my update at the end of the answer

Comment: I got it working with a couple of edits! Thank you much!

Comment: The change that made it work is `If p.Next.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber > p.Range.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber Then`